# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/http' in 'D:\ask\src\app\service'

Tags: angular, laravel

I want to do insertion using laravel and angular, and I want to set HEADERS but it gives me this error.

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/http' in 'D:\ask\src\app\service'

**laravel**

**public/index.php**

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */
```

**angular**

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule , Routes} from '@angular/router';
import { RoutingModuleModule } from './routing-module.module';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; 
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http' ;


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './components/footer/footer.component';
import { TaskManagerComponent } from './components/task-manager/task-manager.component';
import { TaskFormComponent } from './components/task-manager/task-form/task-form.component';
import { TaskListComponent } from './components/task-manager/task-list/task-list.component';
import { TaskDetailComponent } from './components/task-manager/task-detail/task-detail.component';
import { TaskItemComponent } from './components/task-manager/task-list/task-item/task-item.component';
import { from } from 'rxjs';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    TaskManagerComponent,
    TaskFormComponent,
    TaskListComponent,
    TaskDetailComponent,
    TaskItemComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RoutingModuleModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**task.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Task } from '../Task';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Headers , RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TaskService {

  Headers:Headers = new Headers();
  Options:any;

  serveur : string='http://127.0.0.1:8000/';

  constructor(public http:HttpClient) {
    this.Headers.append('enctype','multipart/form-data');
    this.Headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    this.Headers.append('X-Requested-with','XMLHttpRequest');
    this.Options = new RequestOptions({Headers:this.Headers});
   }

  addTask(title):Observable<Task>{
    const newTask=new Task(title);
    //console.log(newTask);
    return this.http.post<Task>(this.serveur+'add',newTask);
  }  
}
```

Comment: `@angular/http` is deprecated. Refer to the release note and documentation to use `@angular/common/http`

Comment: npm install @angular/http

Comment: @penleychan he give me another error "export 'Headers' was not found in '@angular/common/http'

Comment: That's because there is no `Headers` in `@angular/common/http`. https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be using Deprecated APIs and Features.

Please read https://angular.io/guide/deprecations and review the modules that your using.

### Import

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
```

### Usage example

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};
.
.
.
this.http.put<any>(url, o, httpOptions);
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 2):

In task.service.ts, instead of below code

```
import { Headers , RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
```

use this:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
```

and set option like this:

```
 const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 
        'enctype':'multipart/form-data',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-Requested-with':'XMLHttpRequest'
     })
};

addTask(title):Observable<Task>{
    const newTask=new Task(title);
    //console.log(newTask);
    return this.http.post<Task>(this.serveur+'add',newTask, httpOptions);
  }
```

Note: best way to add header by interceptor service.
To add interceptor refer: [best way to add interceptor in angular](https://medium.com/@mohamedaymen.ourabi11/how-to-build-an-http-interceptor-in-angular-framework-8a5091e1b813)

Comment: @s shrif can I erase everything about hearder and replace with this code or I leave everything and I add this code

Comment: you have to remove this import statement
import { Headers , RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

And following code from constructor

this.Headers.append('enctype','multipart/form-data');
    this.Headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    this.Headers.append('X-Requested-with','XMLHttpRequest');
    this.Options = new RequestOptions({Headers:this.Headers});

Comment: you can set header option by

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

Comment: yeah, It should work. I have made changes as per your code

Comment: If you want to follow best practice add an interceptor in your application

Comment: @s I share my new code, please modify it to be compile exactly

Comment: @NajibMarzouk are you still facing same issue or it's fixed?

Answer (score 0):

In your servie `import { HttpHeaders, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http'` instead of `Headers` and `RequestOptions` as they're deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

**plz edit this code for work**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Task } from '../Task';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TaskService {

  Headers:Headers = new Headers();
  Options:any;

  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 
      'enctype':'multipart/form-data',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-Requested-with':'XMLHttpRequest'
   })
};

  serveur : string='http://127.0.0.1:8000/';

  constructor(public http:HttpClient) {
    this.Headers.append('enctype','multipart/form-data');
    this.Headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    this.Headers.append('X-Requested-with','XMLHttpRequest');
    this.Options = new RequestOptions({Headers:this.Headers});
   }

   addTask(title):Observable<Task>{
    const newTask=new Task(title);
    //console.log(newTask);
    return this.http.post<Task>(this.serveur+'add',newTask, httpOptions);
  }  
}
```